# What is the length of the missing distance?

Tags: geometry, arithmetic, physics, fractions

[image]
The book says that the missing distance is $$\frac{L}{2} - \frac{D}{2}$$
I feel like this is something simple that I should understand but I'm just having a disconnect on how they found the distance to be that.

EDIT: added more information with context of the problem

Comment: You'll get more answers if you post an entire problem and not just a part of it.

Comment: @Pawel well the rest of the problem is physics, and I kinda understand what the book is doing in the  rest I'm just having trouble with this specific part which I felt like I have given all the required information on, the book also did not give an explanation because I think its something that I should be able to find out but I'm having a hard time.

Comment: It's impossible to deduce that length from the information given.

Comment: Ok my bad then ill edit in more info

Comment: @Jude Without knowing what the author means by a "missing distance" or what does the graph represent your question is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is that the sawhorses are equidistant from the center of the plank. Therefore the distances between each end of the plank and each sawhorse are also equal, and must be ${L-D \over 2}$.

Answer (score 0):

This would be true if the $L$ measure and the $D$ measure are centred on the same point. Then the L measure extends $L/2$ to the right of the centre point, the $D$ measure extends $D/2$ to the right of the same point, and the gap between them is as given.